# Multiple API Requests of different accounts, how to properly close out each request?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am trying to make multiple calls to the same website for separate accounts. It seems the information from the first call is still stored or 'in the way' when the second call is made. Specifically, the pub ID's from the first account is mentioned in the error spit out by r1 of the second request saying that was not the expected ID. Here is my code making the request, I've tried adding in s.close() but the problem persists:

```
def data(account, report, st, et):     
    url_post = "https://publisher-api.website.com/1.0/Publisher/Login?"
    payload = {'username':account.username,'password':account.password}
    url_get = report.url+"?date_range="+st+"|"+et+""

    with requests.Session() as s:
        r1 = s.post(url_post,data=payload)
        r2 = s.get(url_get)
    s.close()

    data = r2.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['value']['data'])
    return df
```

Here is the code making multiple calls:

```
def rev_all():

    spx_st = spotx_date(grab_date('Start Date: '))
    spx_et = spotx_date(grab_date('End Date: '))

    SP1_Rev = data(SP1, Revenue, spx_st, spx_et)
    SP2_Rev = data(SP2, Revenue, spx_st, spx_et)
    SP3_Rev = data(SP3, Revenue, spx_st, spx_et)
    SP7_Rev = data(SP7, Revenue, spx_st, spx_et)
    SP8_Rev = data(SP8, Revenue, spx_st, spx_et)

    Rev = [SP1_Rev, SP2_Rev, SP3_Rev, SP7_Rev, SP8_Rev]
    df = pd.concat(Rev,ignore_index=True)

    return df
```

Comment: What do you mean 'in the way'. Is the same data being returned?

Comment: I modified data() to print r1,r2 and data, this is the output: <Response [201]> <Response [403]>
{u'error': {u'message': u"The passed Publisher ID '100000' does not match the logged in Publisher ID '111111'.", u'code': u'SYSTEM.SERVICE.IDENTITY_MISMATCH', u'data': {u'publisher_id': u'100000', u'identity': u'111111'}}}

Comment: I don't think there's anything fundamentally wrong with your Python code (`s.close()` is redundant though since you're already using the session context manager via the `with` statement. And I would move the `data = r2.json()` inside the `with` block). You're doing each request pair in a new sessions, so cookies wouldn't carry over. To me this looks like the issue is server side (could also be a caching proxy).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should also do a Logout in each session. I think the problem is that the previous session is still active on the server side as you did a Login but not Logout.

Comment: There is nothing in the documentation that references being able to 'logout', is there anything I can do with the requests module in particular?

Comment: Sorry no idea. Probably you should talk to the developer of the service